# Can I use a gap filler/expanding foam around HVAC vent?

Tags: hvac, gap

Found some mouse turds in the cinder blocks that were knocked out for the hvac off the main basement wall and the side slab. Can I gap fill around this? The vent doesn't appear insulated... should I be worried about sealing it off from the basement temps? Second pic is the first floor and the distance the vent goes from the basement wall out to the end of the slap.

/Cheers

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: pack the space with stainless steel scouring pads. mice do not like to chew metal. .... or use Brillo pads (or equivalent) because the soap will add an extra level of deterrent ... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Brillo_soap_pads.JPG/1280px-Brillo_soap_pads.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know if it's a supply duct (bringing warmed or cooled air from the furnace/AC) or a return duct (taking air back to be processed again).  It looks like the latter.

But in either case, even a supply duct is not so hot that you could not seal the opening with ordinary expanding foam.  I would do that.

Typically supply ducts are covered with some minimal insulation so their air makes it to the room without loosing the temp difference (possibly to the basement as you indicate).   Return ducts are typically not.

You could also pay attention to any leaks in the ducting assembly, and use metal tape or duct mastic to seal them.  Expanding foam would also work around the duct's opening in the floor.

Comment: Supply line. Gonna fill the space with screen/copper mesh and fill it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The power company caulked or used tape around all our duct penetrations ; Some kind of a good will gesture . So it must be approved techniques.